# php handle 2 requests coming through the same TCP connection

Tags: php

I would like to write a simple php script to handle the situation where two HTTP requests coming through the same TCP connection.  More specifically, would like to respond to a request differently if it comes in a tcp connection that has completed a HTTP transaction (vs a tcp connection that has never had any HTTP transaction).

This may be against the principle of php/apache, just curious if there is a way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I might be missing something - when a client connects to the server, they're assigned a file descriptor to hold their socket connection. You listen on :80, and I connect. Your OS stores this to say, FD #1. Now, how is your client going to make ANOTHER request if the first one hasn't been completed? It's not difficult to respond to such a thing, what's difficult (for me) is - how do you establish such a connection? It's a client issue more than server one, isn't it?

Comment: @N.B. Client will always wait for one HTTP transaction to complete before it does another one. There are two cases. 1) client does one HTTP transaction in each TCP connection  2) client performs two HTTP transactions in the same TCP connection.  I would like to create php script to handle the two cases differently.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A php script can use the following to distinguish connections that carry the HTTP requests.

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]:$_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]
```